# Why is var customer.email not being populated in my Transactional Emails?

Tags: email-templates, transactional-mail

Simple question. I am adding the email address to the "New Order" template, but nothing is being populated. Why?

I am simply passing `Login: {{var customer.email}}`

I am passing in several other parameters which populate normally (order number, address, payment amount, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at sendNewOrderEmail() in app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php

```
    $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
            'order'        => $this,
            'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
            'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
        )
    );
```

order, billing, payment_html are the only variables available in that email template (customer is not available)

Try

```
{{var order.customer_email}}
```

See [System Email Template](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/English/Mage_Adminhtml/system_email_template/index/)

Comment: Simple answer for a simple question. Thank you for the link and for relieving my headache.